# Share local server through a router on a Mac

Tags: router, osx-lion, ruby-on-rails

I've built an application using the Rails framework that was designed for two or three iPads to access through a local network. However, the building I will rent does not have an internet connection for me to use. Is it possible to share the local rails server through a router that the iPads can connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can access your application from iPad (or any other device) by specifying the IP address in the browser Eg: 192.168.x.x:3000/ (Assuming rails is running at localhost:3000 on your server machine) if all the devices are connected to the same network.

Comment: I connected my iPad and laptop to [a router](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/WRT55AG?referrer=www.linksysbycisco.com), without the router being connected to the internet, but the iPad can't load the page. I can see in the server logs that it starts making the request, but after about 20 minutes it quits. Is there a setting that I need to change for it to work?

Comment: Does the request from your laptop work fine?

Comment: I switched the server to apache2 with phusion passenger and it's running great.